# How , internally, each array element is getting passed to the callback function used inside the "map" function in javascript

Tags: javascript

How , internally, each array element is getting passed to the callback function used inside the "map" function in javascript.

```
incrementByOne = function (element) {
     return element + 1;
   }

myArray = [1,2,3,4];

myArray.map(incrementByOne); // returns [2,3,4,5]
```

In the above code , we are passing the callback function "incrementByOne" to the "map" function. But I am curious to know that how the function "incrementByOne" gets each array element as its parameter. I know that we are using dot operator with mayArray to call map function , but how it makes the callback function possible to accept each array element as its parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a method is called on an object, the method can examine the object that the method was called upon. The `.map` function is iterating through its `this` (the array) and calling the callback with each element. You could implement the basic functionality yourself like this:

```js
Array.prototype.myMap = function(callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(callback(this[i]));
  }
  return newArray;
};




const incrementByOne = function(element) {
  return element + 1;
}
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(myArray.myMap(incrementByOne)); // returns [2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` in the method of `Array` defined on `Array.prototype`. Inside any method of object you can access the object by using `this` keyword. Below is example of simple custom map method.

```js
function map(cb){
  let res = [];
  for(let i = 0;i<this.length;i++){
    //This is line where the element and index gets passed to the callack.
    res[i] = cb(this[i],i);
  }
  return res
}

Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,'map2',{
  writable:true,
  value:map
})

let arr = [1,2,3];

console.log(arr.map2(e => e+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is the syntax of map.

```
myArray.map(function(val) {
   console.log(val); // Will give you 1 2 3 4
})
```